# ruby sort array of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, enumeration

I'm having a problem figuring out how I can sort an array of an array. Both arrays are straight forward and I'm sure it's quite simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the array:

```
[["happy", 1], ["sad", 2], ["mad", 1], ["bad", 3], ["glad", 12]]
```

I want to sort it by the integer value of the inner array which is a value of how many times the word has occurred, biggest number first.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try either:

```
array = [["happy", 1], ["sad", 2], ["mad", 1], ["bad", 3], ["glad", 12]]
sorted = array.sort {|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}
```

Or:

```
array = [["happy", 1], ["sad", 2], ["mad", 1], ["bad", 3], ["glad", 12]]
sorted = array.sort {|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}
```

Depending if you want ascending or descending.

Answer (score 2):

sort can be used with a block.

```
a = [["happy", 1], ["sad", 2], ["mad", 1], ["bad", 3], ["glad", 12]]
a.sort { |o1, o2| o1[1] <=> o2[1] }
#=> [["happy", 1], ["mad", 1], ["sad", 2], ["bad", 3], ["glad", 12]]
```

Comment: You should *always* use `sort_by` for a keyed sort. Not only is it *much easier* to read, it is also more efficient. In this case it would be `a.sort_by {|el| el[1] }`, which, in this case, is the same as `a.sort_by(&:last)`.

Comment: How can we use this a.sort_by { |el| el[1] } if we want to order it descending?

Comment: @Vini.g.fer  a.sort_by { |el| el[1] * -1} if el[1] is number

Answer (score 1):

Using the Array#sort method:

```
ary = [["happy", 1], ["sad", 2], ["mad", 1], ["bad", 3], ["glad", 12]]
ary.sort { |a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
a = [["happy", 1], ["sad", 2], ["mad", 1], ["bad", 3], ["glad", 12]]
a.sort {|x,y| y[1] <=> x[1]}
```